# What's the right way to conditionally append HTML elements with D3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

In D3.js, how do you achieve the following?

```
selection
    .append('td')
    // if the current datum is X
    .append('a');
    // else
    .append('span');
```

In addition, if my data has the following structure:

```
data = [{
    x: {
        id: 1,
    },
    y: {
        members: [{
            id: 1
        }, {
            id: 2
        }, {
            id: 3
        }]
    }
}, {
    // ...
}, {
    // ...
}]
```

I have `data` bound to a `ul` element, and in each `li` I would like to display the `members` of each entry in a table. So basically

```
list.append('ul')
list.selectAll('li').data(data).enter().append('li')
```

and for each `li`

```
li.append('table')
table.data(function(d) { return d.y.members; })
```

where `d` is an entry of `data`.

Now how do I achieve what's described in the first question, where the condition is `x.id === members.id`? How is a child supposed to access the parent's datum?

Answer (score 0):

Look at selection call https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_call
You can define a function and depending on your parameters you can append and modify your selection

```
function modify(selection, param) {
  if(param === "something"){
      selection
         .append("rect")
         .attr("width", 100)
         .attr("height", 100)
         .attr("x", 100)
         .attr("y", 100)
  }else{
       selection
         .append("text")
         .text("NOTHING")
         .attr("y", 100)
         .attr("x", 100)

  }
}

d3.select("svg").call(modify, "something")
d3.select("svg").call(modify, "")
```